# How to Group result into smaller sub array from mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

I have data in mongo be  like:

```
{

"name":"XYz",
"type":"A"
}

{
"name":"XYz",
"type":"B"
}

{
"name":"XYz",
"type":"C"
}

{
"name":"XYz",
"type":"C"
}
```

suppose if do

```
const alldata=MODEL.find()
```

I want my all data structure to be look like:

```
{
 "A":[
{
"name":"XYz",
"type":"A"
}


],
"B":[
{
"name":"XYz",
"type":"A"
}
],
"C":[
{
"name":"XYz",
"type":"C"
}
,{
"name":"XYz",
"type":"C"
}

]

}
```

is there any direct query in mongoose to do it or do i have to do it manually by getting all objects and then filter and aggregate is accordingly??

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve using [aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/),

- `$group` by type and make array of root documents,
- `$arrayToObject` convert k(key) and v(value) format from array to object
- `$repalceRoot` to replace above converted object to root

```
YourSchemaName.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$type",
      root: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: [[
            {
              k: "$_id",
              v: "$root"
            }
        ]]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XNT6AK23shN)